# Continue a RandomizedSearchCV fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In order to tune some machine learning's (or even pipeline's) hyperparameters, sklearn proposes the exhaustive "GridsearchCV" and the randomized "[RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)". The latter samples the provided distributions and test them out, to finally select the best model (and provide the result of each tentative).

But let's say I train 1'000 models using this randomized method. Later, I decide this isn't precise enough, and want to try 1'000 more models. Can I *resume* the training? Aka, asking to sample more, and try more models without losing current progress. Calling `fit()` a second time "restarts" and discards previous hyperparameters combinations.

My situation looks like the following:

```py
pipeline_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, distribution, n_iter=1000, n_jobs=-1)
pipeline_cv = pipeline_cv.fit(trainX, trainy)
predictions = pipeline_cv.predict(targetX)
```

Then, later, I'd decide that 1000 iterations are not enough to cover my distributions' space, so I *would* do something like

```py
pipeline_cv = pipeline_cv.resume(trainX, trainy, n_iter=1000) # doesn't exist?
```

And then I'd have a model trained across 2'000 hyperparameters combinations.

Is my goal achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9763) on that back from Sep 2017, but it is still open:

> In practice it is useful to search over some parameter space and then continue the search over some related space. We could provide a `warm_start` parameter to make it easy to accumulate results for further candidates into `cv_results_` (without reevaluating parameter combinations that have already tested).

And a similar question in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455729/pause-store-and-resume-hyperparameter-search-with-gridsearchcv-or-randomizedsea) is also effectively unanswered.

So, the answer would seem to be **no** (plus that the scikit-learn community has not felt the need to include such a possibility).

But let's stop for a moment to think if something like that would be really valuable...

---

RandomizedSearchCV essentially works by random sampling parameter values from a given distribution; e.g., using the example from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html):

```
distributions = dict(C=uniform(loc=0, scale=4),
                     penalty=['l2', 'l1'])
```

According to the very basic principles of such random sampling and random number generation (RNG) in general, there is not any *guarantee* that such a randomly sampled value will *not* be randomly sampled more than one time, especially if the number of iterations is large. Factor in the fact that RandomizedSearchCV does not do any *bookkeeping* itself either, hence in principle it can happen that same parameter combinations will be tried more than once in any single run (again, provided that the number of iterations is sufficiently large).

Even in cases of continuous distributions (like the uniform one used above), where the probability of getting *exact* values already sampled may be very small, there is the routine case of two samples being like `0.678918` and `0.678919`, which, however close, they are still *different*, and count as different trials.

Given the above, I cannot see how "warm starting" a RandomizedSearchCV will be of any practical use. The real value of RandomizedSearchCV lies at the possibility of sampling a usually large *area* of parameter values - so large that we consider useful to unleash the power of simple random sampling, which, let me repeat, does not itself "remember" past samples returned, and it may very well return samples that are (exactly or approximately) equal to what has been already returned in the past, thus rendering any "warm start" practically irrelevant.

So effectively, simply running two (or more) RandomizedSearchCV processes sequentially (and storing their results) does the job adequately, provided that we do **not** use the same random seed for different runs (i.e. what is effectively suggested in the [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455729/pause-store-and-resume-hyperparameter-search-with-gridsearchcv-or-randomizedsea) thread mentioned above).

Comment: I see. I hoped to have a more "compact" solution, but I guess running them sequentially as you said probably is the closest we can do now. I still think a warm start or merging instances would provide value, but if sklearn's community hasn't decided to, well too bad. Thanks for your answer!